# Weird app on my andriod. Unable to uninstall it

Tags: applications, malware

Here is this weird drawer/app I am getting when I swipe on bottom left corner of my screen.

I tried to uninstall it, but can't find it in the list.

I believe it is some malware/adware, as it shows random keywords in the search box (in screenshot, it is showing india vs australia). This app came out of nowhere without being preinstalled. I have another phone of same brand/model which is without this creepy app.

I am using Xiaomi Redmi 2

[image]

Comment: I'd almost bet that's a pre-installed system feature. Some Sony devices ship with something similar to be activated from the corners of their screens. [Looks familiar](http://en.miui.com/thread-72937-1-1.html)?

Comment: Thanks @Izzy - I checked the mentioned app, but it is totally different. Installed the same as well and it is listed in apps normally. The above one altogether different with different UI, although some resemblance, and the worst part, listed nowhere.

Comment: I could find a link which has a similar screenshot, but it is written in a different language. http://hotro.mobiistar.vn/threads/cap-nhat-rom-android-lollipop-5-1-cho-mobiistar-prime-x-_-beta.41207/page-13

Comment: That page mentions it could be removed using [CCleaner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.piriform.ccleaner), if I understood it correctly (Google-Trans). But that seems to be a Vietnamese ROM on a Vietnamese phone at a Vietnamese provider. Strange. And the thread doesn't name the app.

Comment: I don't think rooting the device will help, as this app came out of nowhere without being preinstalled. I have another phone of same brand/model which is without this creepy app. The worst thing is battery life has reduced to half. :-(

Comment: OK, that's a fact worth integrating with your question (done), so it didn't come pre-installed. Rooting may in fact be an advantage here (in case the app hid itself, using some exploit to get root access itself). If you cannot find the app, maybe before going to root you try a [factory reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info)? This would delete your data as well as the apps you've installed, but hopefully that app along.

Comment: @Ehs4n Thought it would be iSwipe feature from Clean Mater but I guess its the Omni Swipe app that you have in your phone. See if you can find anything with that name.

Answer (score 1):

That's most likely a MIUI app called [Lazy Swipe](http://en.miui.com/thread-72937-1-1.html):

[image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot]
<sup>*Lazy Swipe* (source: [Miui](http://en.miui.com/thread-72937-1-1.html); click image for larger variant)</sup>

This app might have come pre-installed with your device. I wouldn't consider it malware until proven otherwise. The "random search presets" might even be possible to deactivate. And if you don't like it at all, you can simply deactivate it in settings. Please refer to the [corresponding article/review](http://en.miui.com/thread-72937-1-1.html) for details.

Hint: [Miui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miui) is the GUI (Graphical User Interface) most Xiaomi devices ship with. This is why I hold it much likely the app came pre-installed with your device, and is no malware you've caught somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks @Izzy - I checked the mentioned app, but it is totally different. Installed the same as well and it is listed in apps normally. The above one altogether different with different UI, although some resemblance, and the worst part, listed nowhere.

Comment: I also tried to scan the phone using few antivirus apps like Avast etc, but they didn't detect any issue.

Answer (score 1):

I guess its the [Omni Swipe](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lazyswipe) app. Try to find this in the applications list and uninstall it. Here's a screenshot of this app which looks similar to the one you have,

[image: Omni Swipe Screenshot]

<sub>Omni Swipe screenshot - Click to enlarge the image - [Source](http://www.aplikanologi.com/)</sub>